# How to learn writing REST API's?

Tags: writing, training

I am 31 years old and graduated university in math with a PhD in 2016. Since then I started a startup on my own.

My goal is to transform into a PHP freelancer who works for a 3-9 months in different companies a year and the remaining months for own projects or the project for my parents.

I created a LinkedIn profile and got many request for full-time jobs which I declined until now because I wanted to keep the project with my parents going. I also got some 3 months freelancing offers, but they often included `experience with writing REST API's`.
Although I have used many REST API's to include them in my projects, I never actually written a REST API so that other developer could integrate my REST API into their project (because there is no demand for this).

What would be the best way to learn this skill?
Is that something that one learns only when working in a big tech or middleclass company?

Comment: Hi Dwwarf, welcome to Freelancing.SE! This question is quite off topic, as it is not talking about Freelancing. For learning programming functions, check out Stack Overflow; for programming theories, please check Programmers.SE.

Comment: @CanadianLuke sorry if this is off topic. I thought it does not belong on SO because its not a technical question. I thought its the right place to ask, because its concerning the freelancer career. However, I also noticed that there were no matching tags. Maybe there is no forum for this kind of questions on stackexchange.

Comment: You'll need to check with the `/help/on-topic` pages of each of those sites. In a crunch, you could also try on SE Chat, as many people will answer these kinds of questions there instead.

Comment: @CanadianLuke thx for the hint with the chat, I try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to work at a big company. The basics of it will be very easy for you since you understand the client side already. Yes, you can build REST APIs in PHP but the industry is leaning a lot on node.js for such things now. Find a tutorial online that shows an example in the language of your choice. Usually the server side will involve some kind of data store. Plus client authentication. Some web page titles out there: "How to build powerful REST APIs blazingly fast with Node.js" and "How To Create A Simple REST API in PHP - Step By Step Guide!"